# Instance portals not triggering teleport

Tags: azerothcore, world-of-warcraft

Im having issues entering Utgarde pinnacle and ToC 5 man.

Running straight into the portal triggers no teleport, however if I strafe into the portal it triggers with 100% success.

I cant find anything relating to this problem. And i have no idea where to look for a cause.

Any help to point me in the right direction will be much appreciated

[image: https://imgur.com/ZcX1zxh]

This is how my Utgarde pinnacle portal looks in the SQL.
(heroic portal highlighted)

Comment: make sure you're using the latest version of AC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating Azerothcore repository on the server, recompiling and then importing updates fixed the issue.